# How use ffmpeg api record video and audio programmatically?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

My device have four channel audio data, and two camera.

I want use ffmepg api get theirs stream.

Have some example I can reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the examples you are looking for here:
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/examples.html

Comment: no camera example, I already check out when I ask before.